# 'nm' command doesn't work with "xargs" on my linux

Tags: linux, shell, xargs, nm

I'm on linux and have libmy.so

I can "nm libmy.so", OK. But when I tried:

```
ls libmy.so|xargs nm
```

It prints error:

```
nm: 'libmy.so': No such file
nm: '': No such file
```

It's so odd. Where did I get wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to  `ls libmy.so|xargs nm` when you can `nm libmy.so`? Is this part of another use-case of yours? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Maybe your `ls` is an alias. Try `/bin/ls libmy.so|xargs nm`; on my system it works

Comment: Basile: You're right. Using /bin/ls solves!